# How to solve error Operation not permited, lstat react native on Windows

Tags: windows, reactjs, react-native

ERPM: operation no permitted,lstat`

Answer (score 1):

You always have to clean the project before to run  the app react-native run-android  firstly we need to run this command for windows

> cd android && gradlew clean